# MySQL ordering with GROUP BY and ORDER BY different column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to get unique entId from eav table (entity attribute value). But I also need to sort the value by an attribute from highest to lowest, but this attribute does not exist in all entity, only some entity has this attribute. Entity that has this attribute has to be on top then follow by its value from highest to lowest. Actually I have already achieve this but I have to use total of 1 main query with 2 nested subqueries. For performance wise, now I am trying to see if it's possible to achieve this using only 1 single query, if not possible then with 1 main query + 1 subquery.

Below is a simplified sql and table of real application.

entId is the foreign key for Entity ID

attId is the foreign key for attribute ID

double is the value of that entity

For example,

```
House1 (an entity), price (attribute id = 127), 2000 (value) 

House1 (an entity), latitude (attribute id = 137), 1.33 (value)
```

An entity can have unlimited number of different attributes. House is just one example of an entity category, there can be unlimited number of different categories, such as animal, country, vehicle and in turn each of this can have unlimited attributes.

Here is an attempt, this query get the correct order that I want in that double column, but the entId is not unique, it has duplicate, if I add a DISTINCT, result won't be in order anymore.

```
SELECT
        eav.entId, eav2.attId, eav2.`double`
FROM
          eav eav2 JOIN 
          eav ON eav2.entId = eav.entId AND eav2.status = 'active' AND eav.status = 'active' AND eav.catId  = 53 AND eav2.catId  = 53 
where    
         
         
          (
                  
              (
                       eav.attId = 6
                       and
                       (
                                eav.`int` = 110
                       )
              )     
          )
         
         
GROUP BY
          eav.entId, eav2.attId
HAVING
          COUNT(DISTINCT eav.attId)      >= 1
          
ORDER BY 
    (eav2.attId = 127) DESC,
    (eav2.`double`) DESC
```

Excerpt of the result, you can see the duplicate entId

[image]

Here is another attempt with MAX aggregate, this will get me unique entId and some correct ordering but one incorrect, because that top result with value 3000 shouldn't be on the top, because this value is not belong to the attribute that I am sorting (attId=127), but it actually belong to attId = 137. Because the two aggregate MAX is sorting on their own and independent of each other. Maybe is there a way to make them tied to each other with CONCAT ?

```
 SELECT
        eav.entId, eav2.attId, eav2.`double`, MAX(eav2.attId = 127), MAX(eav2.`double`)
FROM
          eav eav2 JOIN 
          eav ON eav2.entId = eav.entId AND eav2.status = 'active' AND eav.status = 'active' AND eav.catId  = 53 AND eav2.catId  = 53 
where    
         
         
          (
                  
              (
                       eav.attId = 6
                       and
                       (
                                eav.`int` = 110
                       )
              )     
          )
         
         
GROUP BY
          eav.entId
HAVING
          COUNT(DISTINCT eav.attId)      >= 1
          
ORDER BY 
    MAX(eav2.attId = 127) DESC,
    MAX(eav2.`double`) DESC
```

Result :

[image]

What I want is below : No duplicated entId is shown, attId = 127 all on top result, then order by its value from highest to lowest in double column.

[image]

Comment: Could you be a little less vague in the description and specify what entity value is optional and which you want in the result set?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, okay, i have updated the question, please check. But I don't get you by " what entity value is optional"

Comment: First of all, please learn how to use proper `GROUP BY`.  Both code shouldn't have run at all.

Comment: @Eric Okay, but can you tell me what's wrong and what it should be ?

Comment: @William All of those non-aggregated columns must be in the `GROUP BY` clause.  In your second query, when you group the data by `eav.entId`, what happen if you have multiple `eav2.attId` for that particular `eav.entId`???  You can try to run your query in SQL Server or Oracle, pretty sure your query won't even execute because it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an aggregation with sorting.  Something like this:

```
SELECT eav.entId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN eav.key = 127 THEN value end) as price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN eav.key = 137 THEN value end) as latitude
FROM eav 
GROUP BY eav.entId
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but a  house has many attribute, for example 20 attributes, so each of their attribute ID I don't know, so I cannot explicitly specify each attribute ID/key, the only attribute ID that I know is the one that I need to sort, so only attid = 127.